# Do advanced JavaEE containers allow controlling thread priority?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-priority

I have been using Tomcat for a long time, and I am frustrated with the lack of control over threads. Some threads may eat up all the resources of the server, and that can't be controlled in Tomcat.

I'm exploring more advanced JavaEE containers like WebSphere, WebLogic, and JBoss. Do they allow controlling or changing the priority of a thread, or a group of threads, even manually? Furthermore, would they allow controlling the amount of CPU used by a thread?

Thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Read the following artical on Weblogic Server:

[Thread Management](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning1)

[WebLogic Server Performance and Tuning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/topten.html)

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather broad.

There are threads created by the container and there are threads created by applications. Tomcat thread priorities can be changed statically through configuration.

However you have no control over those created by applications unless they have made use of the [javax.enterprise.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-frame.html) facilities that have been added to Java EE 7. Different implementations of this may or may not provide a way of dynamically reconfiguring threads created in this way.

Some Java EE implementations prior to 7 may provide vendor dependent APIs for applications to get access to concurrent capabilities.